# Why are my membership start and join dates being changed?

Tags: civimember, payment-processor, recurring-contributions, auto-renew

On one site that I'm looking after we've recently changed our membership types to enable auto-renewal, and are using [this GoCardless direct debit payment processor](https://github.com/artfulrobot/uk.artfulrobot.civicrm.gocardless) to handle the payments. My assumption was that as existing members began using the auto-renewal, that their join date would be left unaltered, and that the start date would continue to be updated annually, as each annual payment was taken by the direct debit.

However, what we've seen in practice is that the member's join date is overwritten with the data that the new direct debit mandate kicks in. The payment processor developer confirms that the extension code is doing nothing with respect to membership, it is simply handling the payment, so why is CiviCRM overwriting my membership dates in this rather unhelpful way.

Comment: Have seen similar behaviour on one 4.7.31 site using the [Smart Debit Direct Debit processor](https://github.com/mattwire/org.civicrm.smartdebit). Will update here with any resolution. What Civi version is your site on?

Comment: Currently 5.2.1, but i'm pretty sure we've been seeing this issue for a while, so probably dates back to 4.7.x. About to update.

Comment: If this is an issue in core it's likely to affect multiple processors as they all should or will be using Contribution.repeattransaction API and share the same workflow for membership renewals.